# KubernetesPodOperator xcom_push key/values not available to subsequent task with xcom_pull

Tags: airflow

Here is an example of the KubernetesPodOperator I am trying --

```
    set_tag = KubernetesPodOperator(
        namespace='default',
        task_id='set-tag',
        name='set-tag',
        image='ubuntu:18.04',
        xcom_push=True,
        cmds=["/bin/sh", "-c"],
        arguments=['''mkdir /airflow && 
                      mkdir /airflow/xcom && 
                      echo '{"test_key":"test_value"}' > /airflow/xcom/return.json 
        ''']
    )
```

In the next downstream PythonOperator, I am trying to fetch this tag as follows -

```
    def print_tag(**kwargs):
        ti = kwargs['ti']
        print(ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='set-tag', key='test_key'))


    get_tag = PythonOperator(
        task_id='get-tag',
        dag=dag,
        python_callable=print_tag,
        provide_context=True
    )
```

I am using 'airflow test' to first run task 'set-tag' and then run 'get-tag' hoping to see the 'test_value' printed. But the printed value appears as 'None'.

Any pointers are much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that the value has been pushed correctly?

Comment: Yes, I added a sleep to get onto the container and verified this - root@set-tag-5f16b7a9:/# cat /airflow/xcom/return.json 
{"test_key":"test_value"}

Answer (score 1):

For the moment name of argument of KubernetesPodOperator for xcom push is `do_xcom_push`, not `xcom_push`

[Source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/operators/kubernetes_pod.py#L139)

Comment: This didn't work either...  I can't see the XCom entry in the airflow task after the set-tag is done

Comment: Can you check if your base sql_alchemy_conn and you pod variable `CORE_SQLALHEMY_CONN` (do `kubectl describe pod`) is the same?